# Crash error: JNI ERROR: local reference table overflow (max=512)

Tags: java-native-interface, overflow

I got the crash when call the OnProgress() callback  a few times in c thread. The JNIEnv , callback object , methodId are in a global struct.

callback:

```
static void OnProgress(int percent, char *msg) {
    jstring str = (*g_upgrade_cb.env)->NewStringUTF(g_upgrade_cb.env, msg);
    (*g_upgrade_cb.env)->CallObjectMethod(g_upgrade_cb.env, g_upgrade_cb.callback,
                                          g_upgrade_cb.onprogress, percent, str);
    (*g_upgrade_cb.env)->DeleteLocalRef(g_upgrade_cb.env, str);
}
```

call the function like this:

```
    char str[512];
    sprintf(str, "F/W: %.3d %.4d-%.2d-%.2d %ld bytes\n",
            version, fw_year, fw_month, fw_day, image_size);
    OnProgress(0, str);
```

g_upgrade_cb:

```
typedef struct {
    jobject callback;
    jmethodID onprogress;
    JNIEnv *env;
} JniCallBack;
JniCallBack g_upgrade_cb = {};

pthread_create(&g_tid, NULL, UpgradeThread, (void *) callback);
void *UpgradeThread(void *arg) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    int envState = (*g_jvm)->GetEnv(g_jvm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (envState == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        if ((*g_jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(g_jvm, &env, NULL) != 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    g_upgrade_cb.env = env;

    g_upgrade_cb.callback = (jobject) arg;
    jclass jclazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, g_upgrade_cb.callback);
    if (jclazz == 0) {
        LOGD("Unable to find class");
        (*g_jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(g_jvm);
        return NULL;
    }
    jmethodID onprogress = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jclazz, "onProcess",
                                               "(ILjava/lang/String;)V");
    g_upgrade_cb.onprogress = onprogress;


    LOGD("-------start upgrade-----");
    OnProgress(0, "start upgrade");

    OnProgress(0, "end upgrade");
    LOGD("-------end upgrade-----");

......
}
```

Can anyboy help me? thks!

Comment: Why are you ignoring the result from the `CallObjectMethod` call? That's a local reference that just disappears into limbo until you detach the thread from the JVM.

Comment: And seeing as how your `GetMethodID` call indicates that `onProcess` is of type `void`, you shouldn't even be using `CallObjectMethod`; you should be using `CallVoidMethod`.

Comment: @Michael  Great, thank you so much!